# Stuff that must learn first in Android client-server communication

Tags: android

i found some on the internet like async task and socket but still not sure.
Android Experience :  very basic in android programming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking questions, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read the following articles on how to use the **Volley** and **Retrofit**, the two most widely-used networking libraries for Android.

**[Volley Tutotial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)**

**[Retrofit Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)**

Comment: thanks for the answer sir